# Send attachment in form asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, attachment

I have a form that sends the information via email to a work account, however I am not sure how to allow users to attach documents and send them via the contact form.

```
<p>
    Your name:
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
        ControlToValidate="YourName" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="YourName" runat="server" Width="250px" /><br />
    Your email address:
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
        ControlToValidate="YourEmail" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="YourEmail" runat="server" Width="250px" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator23"
        SetFocusOnError="true" Text="Example: username@gmail.com" ControlToValidate="YourEmail"
        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    Subject:
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
        ControlToValidate="YourSubject" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="YourSubject" runat="server" Width="400px" /><br />
    Your Question:
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
        ControlToValidate="Comments" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="Comments" runat="server" 
            TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Width="400px" /><br />
    Upload a file:
    <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" />
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" 
                OnClick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="save" />
</p>
```

and here is my code:

```
protected void SendMail()
    {
        // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
        var fromAddress = "";
        // any address where the email will be sending
        var toAddress = "";
        //Password of your gmail address
        const string fromPassword = "";
        // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
        string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
        string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
        body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
        body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";
        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }
        // Passing values to smtp object
        smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
    }
```

Can someone else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I have used to send a message with an attachment.  It is similar to yours, but I build a MailMessage object, which has an Attachments collection that you can add files to...  If you want users to upload the files, you will need to add the code to save them to the cloud or to your server or someplace where they are accessible until they are sent.

```
public void EmailRO(string recipient, string attachmentPath)
{

        var SMTP = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "YourHost",
            Port = 12345, //your port
            EnableSsl = true, // or false
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("YourUserName", "YourPassword")
        };

        Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            try 
            {
                using (var message = new MailMessage("YourSmtpUserName", recipient)
                {
                    Subject = "My Subject",
                    Body = "My Body",
                    From = new MailAddress("YourUserName", "YourDisplayName"),
                    IsBodyHtml = true
                })
                {
                    {
                        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("YourAttachmentPath"));
                        SMTP.Send(message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                // handle exception
            }
        });
        T1.IsBackground = true;
        T1.Start();

}
```